# Composer.phar. Could not open input file in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using xampp Win 10 and Yii2 Framework. I add: php composer.phar require --prefer-dist imanilchaudhari/yii2-social-share "dev-master" but error: Could not open input file: composer.phar

Help me!!! Thank all.

Comment: Have you installed composer on your pc?

Comment: @KunalRaut yep I has composer.

Comment: Ok i got it this is basically due to the composer not installed to the project root

Comment: You can install composer GLOBALLY on your machine. Since, almost all PHP Projects nowadays uses Composer for Dependency Management. Once you installed manually check its working by running a composer command like `composer --version`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs basically due to the composer being installed in the wrong directory for that you have two options as

1. Make the composer Global

   Change to a directory on your PATH and run the installer following the Download page instructions to download composer.phar.

   Create a new composer.bat file alongside composer.phar:

   **Using cmd.exe:**

   ```
   C:\bin> echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat
   ```

   Add the directory to your PATH environment variable if it isn't already. For information on changing your PATH variable, please see this article and/or use your search engine of choice.
   And to check if it the process is successful or not you can use the command as

   ```
   C:\Users\username>composer -V
   ```
2. Directly install the composer in your project root

   Simply hold down the Shift key and right-click on the desktop. In the context menu, you will see the option to **Open command window** here. Clicking on it will open a CMD window.

   And then simply run the following commands to install the composer for your project root.

   ```
   php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
   php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e0012edf3e80b6978849f5eff0d4b4e4c79ff1609dd1e613307e16318854d24ae64f26d17af3ef0bf7cfb710ca74755a') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
   php composer-setup.php
   ```